# Create dynamic binary columns in sql query

Tags: sql, presto

I'm using presto db

I have two tables, one looks like:

table 1:

```
item    count
p1        20
p2        10
p3         5
p4         4
p5         2
```

and table 2:

```
person        lic
c1             p2
c1             p1
c2             p3
c2             p4
c2             p2
c3             p1
c4             p2
```

I want to return a table that looks like:

```
person      p1    p2    p3   p4   p5

c1          1     1      0   0    0
c2          0     1      1   1    0  
c3          1     0      0   0    0
c4          0     1      0   0    0
c5          0     0      0   0    0
```

It looks like a pivot would do, but im not sure how to account for missing values in the column and get them to be '0' in the final table

Comment: Are you using `count()`? If so, it will already do this...

Comment: @JohnHC am I using count where?

Comment: Where exactly is the "dynamic" and "binary" in this question?

Answer (score 1):

The output schema for a SQL query must be fixed. Thus, if you want a column `p1` to appear in the output, it has to be listed explicitly in the query.

I'm not sure how `table1` is related to the output, but you can do a pivot like this:

```sql
SELECT person
, count_if(lic = 'p1') p1
, count_if(lic = 'p2') p2
...
FROM table2
GROUP BY person
```

The query needs to list each `p` column. Depending on your application, you might be able to generate the query programmatically by first running a query to get the unique values of `p`.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without manually writing out all the columns ? that was what I was trying to avoid

Comment: table 1 is there because I need all rows in table 1 to be present in the final table, a person such as c3 does not have a row for p2, but I still want that to show up in the last table